# Подключение к telnet серверу через http прокси

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, telnet

Есть удаленные сервера, к которым возможно подключиться по телнет через http прокси с авторизацией.

Подключаюсь к прокси серверу с авторизацией:

```
string URL = "http://10.100.23.23:23"; // необходимый сервер 

WebProxy pr = new WebProxy("192.168.0.243:3128");  // указываю прокси сервер
pr.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, password);  // данные авторизации
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
request.Proxy = pr;
request.Method = "CONNECT";
request.Referer = "CONNECT 10.100.23.23:23 HTTP/1.1";
request.Host = "10.100.23.23:23";

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

Console.WriteLine("Stand: {0}",((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

reader.Close();
response.Close();
```

Ответ от прокси сервера приходит корректный, т.е. (200) Доступ разрешен все ОК. А вот какие пакеты мне дальше отсылать и куда, для того что бы общаться с конечным сервером по telnet разобраться не могу.

Сниффер показывает мне на примере работы PuTTy(telnet, ssh, local client), что посылка пакетов далее идет уже по протоколу telnet в направлении прокси сервера, при это пакет в себе содержит

```
HTTP 
[Proxy-Connect-Hostname: 10.100.23.23]
[Proxy-Connect-Port: 23 ]
```

и уже потом в этом же пакете указана команда Telnet.

*Ищу информацию давно, пролистал гугл даже на 4 странице поиска и разные запросы, ответа так и не нашел.*

**Вопрос закрыт. Спасибо за ответы**
Кому будет полезна данная информация:
В случае подключения к телнет-серверу через http-proxy будет правильнее с помощью TCPClient'a
Пример:

`// Сформированный header загружаем из файла по-байтово
byte[] header = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\header.txt");
// Создаем клиент
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
// открываем поток
var stream = client.GetStream();
// отправляем запрос CONNECT к прокси-серверу
stream.Write(header, 0, header.Length);
// Read - собственная функция, обрабатывающая ответ от сервера
textBox1.Text = Read(client);`

После пользуемся потоками: отправляем и получаем информацию. Основная загвоздка - я пытался общаться полноценно с сервером методом HttpWebrequest, а нужно юзать TCPClient

Answer (score 2):

Что значит куда? Пакеты вы должны посылать по тому же соединению. Какие пакеты посылать известно только вам. Я могу лишь сказать, что обычно телнет это текстовый протокол.

Вы можете взять обычный telnet клиент, подключиться на 192.168.0.243:3128, послать CONNECT 10.100.23.23:23 HTTP/1.1 и строку с логином/паролем (Authorization: Basic ...), получить 200 OK и, дальше, по этому же соединению, слать команды серверу telnet.

Comment: Спасибо. Немного уточню: нужно далее отправлять запросы на прокси (192.168.0.243:3128) ? И по какому протоколу (HTTP или уже telnet),  и если http, то каким образом в этот пакет добавить команды telnet?

Comment: Да, на тот же прокси по тому же соединению. Если создавать новое соединение, придется посылать новый запрос CONNECT на прокси. Вы посылаете CONNECT, прокси отвечает 200 OK и все ваши дальнейшие данные пересылает на telnet.